# Hidden secrets in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

So when I played the Terran campaign again after completing the Zerg campaign in Heart of the Swarm, I accidentally uncovered a secret maybe? The one I'm talking about is in the mission where you have to hold for about 20 minutes on the first planet. There is a soldier that will go to a toilet when you see him, then will blast off when clicked three times. So

1. Are there any more of them in the other missions?
2. What does it do?  Does it gives any accomplishment or anything at all?

Comment: There are more, but I don't know them off the top of my head. They're called easter eggs and are generally references to other Blizzard games. They don't do anything, except giving you the feeling you found something special and funny.

Comment: Why down voted?

Comment: my question too.

Comment: Seems to be on-topic as per [What defines a question as being too broad when asking about easter eggs?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8133/4797)

Comment: look into youtube for more easter eggs and secret missions...

Comment: @galacticninja but both of the questions are open and answered

Comment: @ken Yep. I'm saying that this question should be left open (as it is on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are a lots of secrets in the campaigns of starcraft 2. However that tauren marine escaping in a tiolet is not trigerred by playing WOL after HOTS. It's just the way there is, if you cleared out that area with your army then the event is trigerred. You can more of these secrets on the following links
http://www.nowgamer.com/top-10-secrets-starcraft-2-wings-of-liberty/
http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/939643-starcraft-ii-wings-of-liberty/cheats